# react.js - react-alert - Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code in my `react.js` application :

```
import { withAlert} from "react-alert";
 class Signup extends React.Component {
state={email:'',passwordHash:'',rePasswordHash:''};
onButtonClick = () =>{
    if(this.state.passwordHash!==this.state.rePasswordHash){
        this.props.alert.error("Wrong password");
    }
    else{
        this.props.alert.show("Creating new account");
    }
};
render(){
    return(
                    <ButtonActor name="Sign In" onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick} />
    );
}
}
export default withAlert()(Signup);
```

It's in my `SignUp` class, whenever user try to create account, it just takes password entered in both fields are same or not. According to that it should create an alert. But it is crashing and gives me this error:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

[react-alert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert), the library I'm using.

Can anyone help me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Move your const alert=useAlert(); out from the function

Comment: @Satif where should I put it?

Comment: @Satif please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hgp.png)

Comment: do you have class component or function component?

Comment: I have `class` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just wrapped `<App/>` with `<AlertProvider/>`.**

Sample from doc, now they have better doc :

```
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'
import App from './App'

// optional cofiguration
const options = {
  // you can also just use 'bottom center'
  position: positions.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  timeout: 5000,
  offset: '30px',
  // you can also just use 'scale'
  transition: transitions.SCALE
}

const Root = () => (
  <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
    <App />
  </AlertProvider>
)

render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

And this one :

```
// App.js
import React from 'react'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'

const App = () => {
  const alert = useAlert()

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        alert.show('Oh look, an alert!')
      }}
    >
      Show Alert
    </button>
  )
}
```

They have interface for button too :

```
import React from 'react'
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert'

const App = ({ alert }) => (
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      alert.show('Oh look, an alert!')
    }}
  >
    Show Alert
  </button>
)

export default withAlert()(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class component, then:

```
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
...
export default withAlert()(Home)
```

and call it as:

```
this.props.alert.show()
```

Comment: I have added almost full code of my `class`, please see. It doesn't work. And gives me error , saying : *Cannot read property 'show' of undefined*

Comment: did you add withAlert() to export?

Comment: yes, as you suggested, I have updated the question , please see

Comment: need to add AlertProvider and AlertTemplate to root component

Comment: My `root` is based on `Router` , `ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));`......... if I try to `<AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate}> <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/> </AlertProvider>`... then things break up..